# financialAnalyses data missing in Google's Solar API - findClosest method

Tags: google-solar-api

Has anyone seen data in the financialAnalyses section of the solarPotential object returned by the Google's SolarAPI: findClosest method?  I've looked through over 30,000 queries of Los Angeles County locations, and I've seen none of them populated with any financialAnalyses data.  The rest of the solarPotential object is populated with data, just missing the financialAnalyses.

Ran the [https://solar.googleapis.com/v1/buildingInsights:findClosest?location.latitude=[latitude]&location.longitude=[longitude]&requiredQuality=HIGH&key=[APIkey]](https://solar.googleapis.com/v1/buildingInsights:findClosest?location.latitude=%5Blatitude%5D&location.longitude=%5Blongitude%5D&requiredQuality=HIGH&key=%5BAPIkey%5D) against many 10,000's of locations.  All the data is populated as expected except the financialAnalyses object within the solarPotential object.

Comment: Works for me, here is an example request where I can see financialAnalyses:  curl "https://solar.googleapis.com/v1/buildingInsights:findClosest?requiredQuality=HIGH&location.latitude=34.17419792166559&location.longitude=-118.32546639123017%key=[YourApiKey]

Can you add a full response you are getting? Please contact support in case you don't want to share a specific location publicly.

You an find support here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/solar/support#creating-a-support-case